# Парсер на PHP, алгоритм

Tags: php, парсер

Знаю как получить документ, нашел библиотеки для обработки полученного документа, но не знаю как дать программе понять где надо остановиться чтобы не парсилось снова то, что было уже спарсено. И как реализовать переход по постраничной навигации, тоже.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, примерно куда копать, что искать, что почитать. Или поделитесь примерным алгоритмом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Искренне не понимаю сути вопроса... но, если вам нужно нормально парсить на пхп, то вам нужно:

1) знание curl (и multicurl);

2) знание строковых функций пхп (как минимум strlen, strpos, substr, str_replace) и циклов (while и do+while);

3) умение писать регулярные выражения (тестировать их удобно тут https://regex101.com ).

Так же вы должны иметь понимание о работе с массивами и строками в общем. Все остальное - сочетание трех вышеперечисленных элементов.

Answer (score 2):

чтобы программа не парсила то, что уже было спарсено, надо задать ей условие "если это еще не спарсено - это надо парсить, иначе - не надо парсить" :)